# how to make command exit in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my exit button...even thought i use "fscommand" when i click exit button it doesn't close my flash game...another button is going well..

```html
package
{
 import flash.display.*;
 import flash.events.*;
 import flash.geom.*;
 import flash.text.*;
 import flash.utils.*;
 import flash.ui.*;
 import flash.system.fscommand;


public function startMenu()
  {
   btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
   btnHelp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHelp);
   btnExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoExit);
  }
  
  private function gotoExit(evt:MouseEvent)
  {
   btnExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoExit);
   fscommand("quit", "");
  }

        private function gotoHelp(evt:MouseEvent)
  {
   btnHelp.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHelp);
   gotoAndStop("Help");
  }
  
  private function gotoGame(evt:MouseEvent)
  {
   btnPlay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
   gotoAndStop("game");
  }
```

Comment: You publish for what? Web, AIR, other ... ?

Comment: for game flash? That's not a publish target at all. You have no idea where your game is gonna run? Beginner?

Comment: `fscommand("quit")`, not `fscommand("quit", "")`. BTW this command is pointless and may not work in browser. When user wants to quit, he can just close the window.

Comment: It will be run in flash player..i'm not publishing to AIR or web...just make it to .swf and run in flash player...so i need button exit work to close flash player...and yes i'm nubie

Comment: So what should i write to make flash player app closed when i click exit button???

Comment: try `System.exit(0);`

Comment: @IrfanSyah Did you got some errors and are other buttons working ?

Comment: No error...all button is ok except exit button ...can't close flash player sven thought i clck exit button

Comment: When i use System.exit(0); ...show some error #2018:System.exit is only available in the standalone flash player ..... at flash.system::System$/exit()

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what "close my Flash game" means to you. `fscommand` will close a Flash projector (.exe, .app). `System.exit()` will close a standalone Flash Player. There's no general way to "close" a Flash Player plugin instance running in the browser, because that's really up to the browser. Explain what you want to happen.

Comment: I want to close this in flash projector(.exe, or .app)

Comment: Ok, in that case `fscommand("quit")` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Adobe, [`fscommand()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html) and [`System.exit()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#exit%28%29) are available only for Flash Player Standalone version (and debugger for `System.exit()` which is not correct).

Take this example of code :

```
btn_fscommand_quit.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        fscommand('quit');
    }
)
btn_system_exit.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        try {
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(error:Error){
            log.text = error.toString();
        }
    }
)
```

Which I tested and it's working fine with a release version of Flash Player 11 :

[image]

You can download the fla (CS6), the swf and a projection (.exe) from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/dyjk1xfiy0m4kl3/exit_swf.zip).

Hope that can help.

Comment: ok thank you it really helpfull ...this command is work very well :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your gotoExit method, you wrote :

```
btnExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoExit);
```

instead of :

```
btnExit.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoExit);
```

Comment: I also try to use  that command but result is still the same...still can't close my game ...

Comment: I use adobe flash cs 6 and AS 3