# I run my program there is no error, but my button does not function in .swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my AS3 code :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.system.fscommand;

ExitIt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Comment: You have just to open your swf in a standalone flash player. Take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28782187/2256820), it contains what you are looking for.

Comment: So, you just pasted a bunch of actionscript lines. What are we supposed to do with this? Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a proper question.

Comment: @Oldskool Well, the question is incomplete, although derivable from the code. `fscommand("quit")` should quit the something and it doesn't. The first comment is a pretty valid answer about reproducing the behavior intended.

Answer (score 0):

fscommand("quit") only works in standalone player. If you have published the flash project as .exe and open it as a normal exe file it will work.